# Log gulp sass written files

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I'm using Gulp to compile SASS code with [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) plugin. I want to log out what files were written (or overwritten) when I run the task, but it does not show me what happened. Only when it is done.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(filesToCompile)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folderToOutput));
});
```

I found the plugin [gulp-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tap) to see what files are going through the stream but it seems to log me out all SASS files, not what files were written or overwritten.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const tap = require('gulp-tap');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(filesToCompile)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
      console.log(file.path);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folderToOutput));
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using the plugins [gulp-changed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed) and [gulp-using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-using). I don't have time to test it at this moment, but I think this code would be :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var using = require('gulp-using');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(filesToCompile)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(changed(folderToOutput))
    .pipe(using({color:'red'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(folderToOutput));
});
```

Here `gulp-changed` filters the files so you only copy new or modified files and `gulp-using` logs you all the files that are passing through the stream after the filter.

PD: You have a typo in your first code snippet.

Comment: Apparently gulp-changed filters everything and nothings get compiled that way. If I remove gulp-changed and leave alone gulp-using, it logs me out all compiled CSS files. Is this a problem with gulp-changed and gulp-sass packages?

Comment: If you don't change anything in the SASS file there's no problem. You have to make any change to see if it works correctly.